# How to structure table in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

[image]

I have four fields: payload, receivedOn, topic, uuid.
I have taken date[milliseconds] as primary key [partition key].
I want to write a query that gives me result based on receivedOn field.
I have tried to scan the database but it does not give result in ascending and descending format.
When I use query I have to use date[partition key] and receivedOn both.

[image]

As you can see I have to assign value in Partition key, but all my partition key is different. So how should I structure my database so I can query on receivedOn field and can get data in descending order.

Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer:
[image]

In dynamoDB partition key is combination of two keys : primary key and sortKey. You can sort your data using sortKey. Partition key can be same but sortKey cannot. So I give receivedOn value to sortKey and add the millisecond to it so it will always be unique.

Comment: Hopefully someone more conversant than me in DynamoDB will come along and address this, but it sounds like you are trying to use DynamoDB like you would use a relational database.  Date-derived values are not a viable partitition key -- you will always have a hot key and it will not scale properly.

Comment: I have successfully designed the database. And now I am getting the results which I want.

Comment: Please post your solution as answer, below, for the benefit of future visitors.

Comment: I have updated the answer.